# In app purchase issue "Your order could not be processed"?

Tags: android-billing

I have been working in "In App Subscription", i followed all the steps given in http://www.robotmedia.net/2011/06/android-billing-library-in-app-billing-made-simple/ everything works fine but when i try to purchase and do payment i got "Your payment could not be processed. Please try again" and i log i got some errors like

```
03-11 18:19:14.489: E/Volley(10235): [13] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/completePurchase
03-11 18:19:14.535: W/Finsky(10235): [1] CheckoutPurchase.onErrorResponse: DisplayErrorMessage[Your order could not be processed. Please try again.]  
03-11 18:19:14.539: E/Finsky(10235): [1] CheckoutPurchase.setError: type=UNKNOWN, code=-1, permissionCode=-1, message=Your order could not be processed. Please try again.
```

I have been breaking my head for past three days. Can some one help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This usually means you are using the same account to buy the in-app purchase as the one you are selling the in-app purchase with. Google does not allow this.

If you want to do this for testing purposes, please check the following page: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

Comment: Hi leaon, yes i know that the google will not allow to use the same account for selling and buying but i used the different accounts only. But still i am getting the same error.

Comment: Anyone? I'm also facing this error out of the blue.